# How to remove unknown properties in typescript

Tags: typescript, axios

I'm using [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) for ajax requests, and using the [deepmerge](https://github.com/TehShrike/deepmerge) library to merge a  couple of objects together. Here's my code snippet:

```
axios.interceptors.response.use((response) => {
  return response;
}, (error) => {
  let basicResponse = deepmerge(error.response, { responseText: error.request.responseText });
  // @ts-ignore
  delete basicResponse.config;
  // @ts-ignore
  delete basicResponse.data;

  return Promise.reject(error);
});
```

I don't want an exact clone of the merged object; there are a few properties I want to remove (in this example, config and data).  If remove the first `//@ts-ignore` comment, then typescript complains:

> Property 'config' does not exist on type '{ responseText: any; }'.

How do I remove the `//@ts-ignore` comments and still access the properties that typescript knows nothing about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this

```
axios.interceptors.response.use((response) => {
  return response;
}, (error) => {
  let basicResponse: any = deepmerge(error.response, { responseText: error.request.responseText });

  delete basicResponse.config;
  delete basicResponse.data;

  return Promise.reject(error);
});
```